# How to get remote Gem path with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, remote-debugging

Hi I want to get a path to gem on remote machine  with capistrano.

I  have the following :

```
namespace :stanford do

  desc "Copy language assets"
  task :copy, :roles => :app  do
    puts Gem::Specification.find_by_name("ruby-opencv").gem_dir   
  end
end
```

This returns path to gem on my local machine..

I tried doing it via capistrano's run (run "#{Gem::Specification.find_by_name("ruby-opencv").gem_dir}") but to same effect.

Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `capture` command to get the result from the remote machine. If your project uses bundler, try this (tested on Capistrano 3 only):

```
namespace :stanford do

  desc "Copy language assets"
  task :copy, :roles => :app  do
    puts capture(:bundle, 'show', 'ruby-opencv')   
  end
end
```

If not using bundler, the following might work:

```
namespace :stanford do

  desc "Copy language assets"
  task :copy, :roles => :app  do
    puts capture(%(ruby -e "puts Gem::Specification.find_by_name('ruby-opencv').gem_dir"))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace :stanford do
  desc "Copy language assets"
  task :copy, :roles => :app  do
    run %(ruby -e "puts Gem::Specification.find_by_name('ruby-opencv').gem_dir")
  end
end
```

There is also a way directly through the gem shell command:

```
gem contents ruby-opencv |head -1 |sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,'
```

but this may not be 100% reliable.

Comment: first command returns "Cannot find gem", second - empty string.. I am 100% sure I have that gem, maybe something to do with Capistrano infrastructure - it installs gems into 'shared' folder, while these commands list gems I have installed in the system (I think)...